# You Did not select a file to upload.But the image is uploaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I found so many questions with this same error . But those answers did not clear my error and still the error remains

when i try to upload image . this error comes

> " **You Did not select a file to upload** "

But the **image is uploaded in the correct location** ..

**Controller**

```
class image extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->load->library('layout');

    $this->load->model('admin_m');

    $this->load->library('upload');

  }

  function projects_more() {

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $config['max_size'] = '100000';

    $config['max_width'] = '102400';

    $config['max_height'] = '76800';


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->layout->view('home_page', $error);

    } else {

        $data   = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $data1  = $this->upload->data();
        $image  = $data1['file_name'];
        $project  = $this->input->post('project');


        $content= $this->input->post('content');

        $this->admin_m->projects_more($image,$project,$content);
        redirect('image/projects_more');

    }
  }
}
```

**My view page**

projects1.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('image/projects_more'); ?>

<table>

<tr>

<td><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" size="20"></td>

</tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Please add your view file too.

Comment: `You Did not select a file to upload` is not a php error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry . it was my mistake. the function projects_more uploads the image first time and at the end of the function i redirected to same function where there is no file to upload . first time it uploads the image and second time it doesn't..sorry for wasting your time. thanks Deniz B.

now i redirected to index function that shows the view page to select the next image and its details ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this -> load -> library('upload');

$config =   array
(
'upload_path'   =>  'yourUploadPath',
'allowed_types' =>  'png|jpg|gif',
);
$this -> upload -> initialize($config);
$this -> upload -> do_upload('photo');
```

If you want to upload your file to `uploads` folder which is there in same folder with `application` and `system` folders, your upload path should be like this:

```
'upload_path'   =>  'uploads',
```

By the way, you don't need to load libraries and helpers page by page, you can use `autoload.php` file which is under `application/config` folder.

Comment: No problem with image upload . Image uploads successfully.  But An error message also displaying. How can i avoid that  error message.

Comment: Remove this part of code:

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());